# How to replace escaped symbol with its actual value?

Tags: c++

I have a string like `escape new lines\n`. When printing it, it doesn't replace `\n` with a new line, it just prints `escape new lines\n`. I'm iterating over this `std::string`, and I want to replace `\n` with it's actual value:

```cpp
bool seenSlash = false;
for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); ++index) {
    if (text[index] == '\\') {
        seenSlash = true;
        continue;
    }
    if (seenSlash) {
        // what to do here?
        seenSlash = false;
    }
}
```

It's not just `\n`, I want to support all of those escaping symbols. How can I do it?

Comment: `if(text[index] == 'n') {/* there was a \ and an n, what do you want to do now? */}` ?

Comment: I did a [C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830321/how-to-write-text-containing-newline-given-as-command-line-arguments-in-c/64830430#64830430) for this a few days back, which could easily be adapted for C++ if you have literal *backslash `n`* in your string.

Comment: @tadman Looks good but is it possible to achieve without pointers?

Comment: Maybe you're just escaping it wrong. The escaped version IMHO should be "\\\n" not "\\n"

Comment: @Zaffy I get this as is input from Flex (the lexical analyser)

Comment: Pointers are the easiest way to iterate over this string at a low level, but you could always try with `std::string` manipulation using the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

WHat you could do is a `switch` statement or using a constant `std::map<char,char>`:

```
if (seenSlash) {
    bool replace = false;
    switch(text[index]) {
    case 'n':
        replace = true;
        text[index-1] = '\n';
        break;
    case 't':
        replace = true;
        text[index-1] = '\t';
        break;
    // ... etc.
    }
    if(replace) {
        text.erase(text.begin() + index); // erase the cuurent char, the
                                          // backslash char was replaced
        --index; // adapt the index for the next iteration
    }
    seenSlash = false;
}
```

---

```
const std::map<char,char> escaped_chars = {
    { 'n', '\n' } ,
    { 't', '\t' } ,
    { 'a', '\a' } ,
    // ... etc.
};

if (seenSlash) {
    bool replace = escaped_chars.find(text[i]) != escaped_chars.end();
    if(replace) {
        text[index - 1] = escaped_chars[text[i]];
        text.erase(text.begin() + index); // erase the cuurent char, the
                                          // backslash char was replaced
        --index; // adapt the index for the next iteration
    }
    seenSlash = false;
}
```

Comment: After erasing the backslash , should I do `index--`?